# How to check for new messages in the Outlook web app?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, web-application

Surely, this is a simple thing and not worthy of StackExchange superuser.  But my search in the internet shows only that several other people have this same question, and aren't getting an answer from MS.  So, I am trying to use the Outlook web app.  How do I check for new messages?  The advertised button for doing so just isn't there AFAICT.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to refresh it.

New e-mails appear as soon as they arrive into your mailbox.

(I haven't find any reference for it, however tested and it works like this)

Comment: Sorry, but my testing doesn't show this at all.  I have found another web site where the claim is that it checks every half hour, which I don't consider frequent enough.

Comment: I've just sent a mail to myself from another account and received it in 10 seconds. As I wrote my inbox was updated automatically.

Comment: Well, I hope I don't sound sarcastic when I say congratulations.  But I did the same thing and it took much longer.  So many minutes, in fact, that I gave up waiting.  Other people on the internet are having similar problems.